# Chrome Extension - The pop-up window will open automatically if my condition is true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a little issue with my chrome extension. I want if active tab is URL that I want, automatic open popup.html of my chrome extension. For example if user opens stackoverflow.com, my popup, opens automatic.

another question: Need I background.js for develop chrome extension or I can develop my app without this.
Now I have a `index.html` and `index.js`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions cannot programmatically open their popups. The user must either click the browser action or perform an equivalent action (e.g. mapping a [command](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/#usage) to `_execute_browser_action`).

Background scripts are not required. You can have a fully functional extension that only uses the browser action popup window.